# Can I learn blender and in future work in any animation studio, without needed to learn script language?

Tags: python

I'm 2d animator, graphic designer, musician. 
Software knowledge : Toon Boom Harmony, Illustrator, Photoshop, After Effects, Sketchbook Pro

Comment: Scripts are useful not only in animation and some tasks can only be done with them. Learn scripting if you want to do anims for a living. And next time give Blender more focus in your questions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Learning to script is totally unnecessary. As an animator, you need to know how to animate. You will be hired as an animator for your skills in animation, and most of the functions are already automated in programs like Blender. If you have an idea with the animation but it's impossible to do without scripts, you have a high chance to find a tutorial for your requirements, or just asking help from people who know their stuff can definitely get it solved for you.